# Need help on deleting a registry folder/key from Windows 10 Ent. 1709

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-registry, windows-10-v1709

I have a folder/key located under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{F0D63F85-37EC-4097-B30D-61B4A8917118}
```

I would like to delete it but doesnot seem I have permission to do so. Here below are what I tried already to fix the issue:

- My account is local admin and also tried to run regedit as administrator
- I tried to set new owner to SYSTEM but got denied.
- I tried to set "Replace all child object permissions entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" on parent folder but got denied.
- Since permissions window is empty for the folder/key, I tried to add SYSTEM and gave full control. But got denied when apply (screenshots are at links below)

https://pasteboard.co/GQvjFup.png

https://pasteboard.co/GQvkxW6.png

https://pasteboard.co/GQvkFsY.png

https://pasteboard.co/GQvl4wh.png

https://pasteboard.co/GQvkRNq.png

I do have a registry backup that doesnot have the folder/key. So is there a way to just replace the current registry with my backup in order to get rid of that folder/key?

Comment: When you attempted to chnage the owner to your current Administrator account what happen?  You can revert the registry with the backup you have unless you use a System Restore point.  Even then I suspect due to the key ownership not being a user on the installation in question it’s very likely attempting to restore a system restore point will simply fail. Simplest solution use the registry editor within WinRE to delete the key.

Comment: @Ramhound, Thanks alot and WinRE saved day!! I just changed permission within WinRE for the Registry Key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this at your own risk.

You can restore the registry permissions using the "tweaking all in one"

http://filehippo.com/download_tweaking-com-windows-repair/

You Will a list of all the available options, but I suggest you to select restore registry defaults.